# Slow PyCharm intellisense

Tags: python, matplotlib, intellisense, pycharm, canopy

Why `Pycharm` intellisense is slow when using scientific packages (Enthought Canopy) and possibly other packages. For example for this screenshot:

[image]

It takes two-three seconds to show the functions. Besides this why there are other packages functions in this list? It should contains only `matplotlib.pylab` package as `plt`.

Comment: That has always been the case for me, numpy behaves similarly. There is a lot happening in the init file and 958 methods imported

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Anyway to change this behavior?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, if you know what you want to import  just import them at the start.

Comment: You could capture a [CPU snapshot](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/29983118-Reporting-performance-problems) and report this performance problem to [PyCharm's issue tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY).